# How to post image file type in postman or rest client form data?

Tags: android, postman, multipart, advanced-rest-client

I did one project in Android (Retrofit) ,I could have gotten response fine in APP,but I don't know how to get response in Postman and Advanced REST client , my issue is how do I send file Type(I don't know what to call it is),In project I achieved by putting  `new TypedFile("image/png",...` but how would I put these parameters in Postman and Advanced REST client? I want to check and know about it, I searched lot and I tried lot but no result. Please help me...

Here is project code:

```
 MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
    try {
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("originalImgBlob", new TypedFile("image/png", files.get(0)));
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("img430Blog", new TypedFile("image/png;base64", files.get(1)));
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("img200Blog", new TypedFile("image/png;base64", files.get(2)));
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("img100Blog", new TypedFile("image/png;base64", files.get(3)));
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("blurResponseBlob", new TypedFile("image/png;base64", files.get(4)));
        Log.d("UploadActivity", "postNewsFeed() returned: " + "" + files.get(2));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    doServereCall(multipartTypedOutput);
```

```
/* Set profile pic in registration */
@Headers("Accept:application/json")
@POST("/api/mbrphotos/prfImgIU/{memberId}/{actionType}")
public void sendMultiImages(@Path("memberId") String memberId,
                            @Path("actionType") String actionType,
                            @Body MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput, Callback<JsonObject> callback);
```

Comment: trying using the primitive type for string, float, integer and choose file type for images

Comment: I want to know where shall I use it? postman or Advanced rest client?

Comment: postman would be good to use

Comment: In postman, if we see body,there is form-data, here key and value pair is available, but there is no option content type.

Answer (score 2):

You can check API response in postman by following steps :

1. selecting **post** method .
2. Then in that select **body** option .
3. now select **form-data** option. after that you have new view that available for enter **key** and **value** .
4. Here you can check your API . I also attach image as source for your help. And select file type in **key** field to post as File Type  . After selecting file type `Choose files` Browse button is available to you to select file.[image]

Comment: Nope, I have to send image type. 'choose image file'   we can select image, but I want to send content type ex: image/png;base64, how do I do..

Comment: if you want to send image as base64 string then your image can be send as simply string.just as other text parameter.

Comment: what about image/png? I would like to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

In Advanced REST Client go to "Body" tab and choose "Any file data" to enable file upload.

[image]

Comment: I tried what you said Mr.Paweł Psztyć  I want to send image file type ex: image/png with selected image to with  this key(originalImgBlob) , how do I send all these three like key,value pair to API?

Comment: @Lokesh - it depends what kind of data your server accepts. If it's url encoded form then use appropriate form with the data.